# Laravel - Como recuperar os valores de um formulário e redirecionar usando a classe Route?

Tags: laravel, formulário

Estou estudando Laravel e no momento estou tentando entender como enviar valores de formulários para serem recuperados e em seguida redirecionar para uma página específica. Ainda estou começando com o Laravel e nem sei se é assim que se faz.

Então, digamos que eu tenha o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="userName"
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

E aqui tenho 2 dúvidas:

1. Não sei se esse é o lugar correto de recuparar os dados do formulário
2. Não sei se essa é a maneira correta de fazer.

Em laravel eu tenho a seguinte rota :

```
Route::post('/action_page',function(){
    $userName = Input::get('userName');//Não sei se isso está correto. 
    if($userName=='paulo'){
        retur view('pagina_paulo');
    }
    elseif($userName=='jose'){
        retur view('pagina_jose');
    }


});
```

Esse é o erro que aparece:

```
methodNotallowedhttpexception in routecollection.php ...
```

Pesquisei nessa [página](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recupera os dados no `Controller`!

Na sua `View` no formulário ficaria assim:

```
<form action="/action_page" method="post">
   ...
```

No arquivo **routes.php**:

```
Route::post('/action_page', 'SeuController@redireciona');
```

E por último no seu **`SeuController`**:

```
public function redireciona(Request $request)
{
    //Recupera o userName do input
    $usuario = $request->input('userName');
     ...
}
```

Usei o objeto [`Request`](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request) que obtém uma instância da atual requisição HTTP.

**Obs:** Para usar a classe `Request` tem de declarar: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` no topo de seu `Controller`

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo, o erro acontece por que você está tentando enviar um post para a rota `/action_page.php` (definido no seu formulário), sendo que você define somente a rota `/action_page`.

Vou fazer algumas alterações no seu código e deixar da maneira mais clara o possível para que você entenda um fluxo básico de requisições e respostas envolvendo parâmetros. Modifique sua `view` para que fique desta forma (recomendo remover a extensão da rota na action do formulário):

```
@if (Input::has('username'))
    <p>O valor antigo do campo username é {{ Input::old('username') }}.</p>
@endif

<form action="/action">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Em seguida, vamos fazer com que esta rota responda com um método de um `controller`, faça as seguintes alterações:

app\Http\routes.php

```
Route::post('/action', 'ExampleController@action');
```

Agora precisamos de um controller, você pode criar via linha de comando com `php artisan make:controller ExampleController` ou manualmente, deixe-o desta forma:

app\Http\Controllers\ExampleController.php

```
..

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function action(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput($request->all());
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, você vai perceber que quando o formulário for enviado, nossa rota nos direciona até o método `action` do `example controller`, que, em seguida, nos redireciona de volta para o formulário utilizando o `redirect()->back()`. Esta parte específica do código:

```
..

->withInput($request->all())

..
```

faz com que os parâmetros anteriores (do formulário) seja enviado junto com o redirecionamento (para a página do formulário novamente), e, esta outra parte específica (do formulário):

```
@if (Input::has('username'))
    <p>O valor antigo do campo username é {{ Input::old('username') }}.</p>
@endif
```

mostra o parâmetro anterior com o nome de username.

Comment: Boa explicação mas pelo que entendi ele não que voltar para página do formulário e sim pegar o usuário e verificar quem é, e então redirecionar para página certa!

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @IgorMello, eu simplesmente quis mostrar o trajeto dos parâmetros de uma forma simples, desse jeito ele mesmo consegue criar a lógica e aplica-la em suas necessidades. Também coloquei uma resposta para o problema principal, que no caso é de rota inválida.